# SQL UPDATE query with prepared statement syntax issue, no error message

Tags: php, sql

After fixing various issues, this finally returns no PHP errors, but doesn't update the database...
Maybe it's the syntax of this piece of code ?

The variables $postId, $id, $comment returns correctly in other functions...

```
public function updateComment($postId, $id, $comment) {   
    $db = $this->dbConnect();
    $commentUpdate = $db->prepare(
        'UPDATE comments SET comment, comment_date VALUES(:comment, NOW()) 
         WHERE post_id = :post_id AND id = :id'
    );
    $affectedLines = $commentUpdate->execute(array(
        'comment' => $comment,
        'post_id' => $postId,
        'id' => $id,
    ));
    return $affectedLines;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is not valid, you seem to be mixing the `UPDATE` and `INSERT`syntax.

You probably want:

```
UPDATE comments 
SET comment = :comment, comment_date = NOW()
WHERE post_id = :post_id AND id = :id
```

NB: your question indicates that you are not properly checking for errors when running SQL queries. Error checking is a critical part of any application code that interacts with a database, as it helps sorting things out when unexpected behavior happens. You might want to have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-information-in-different-environments) for more information on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this SQL in the prepared statement

```
UPDATE comments SET comment = :comment, comment_date = NOW() WHERE post_id = :post_id AND id = :id
```

VALUES is typically used for an INSERT, rarely for an UPDATE.